# Play custom shaking effect before default revert animation for droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I have an `draggable` and `droppable` elements at my website. I want to make the `draggable` element shaking when user tries to drop it on wrong container and **then** revert it's position.

So far I have the code that does it all without the shaking effect:

```
$('#elementID').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$container.droppable({
    accept: function(dropElem){
        return ($(this).attr("meta-ok") === "true"); //return false if it's "wrong" container
    },
...
```

When I drop element on "wrong" container it does revert the position of element (good), but there's no "shaking" before that revert animation takes place.

I was trying to add `$(...).effect('shake')` from [jQueryUI](https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/), but how to play it **before** the revert animation and then go with the "standard" revert animation (I don't want to replace the default revert animation, but insert my shaking before it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `revert` animation happens on `mouseStop` and is nested in different validations, which makes it hard to modify directly. But you could create a `custom draggable` and modify the revert animation. Like this:

```
$.widget("ui.customDraggable", $.ui.draggable, {
    _mouseStop: function(event) {

        //If we are using droppables, inform the manager about the drop
        var that = this,
            dropped = false;
        if ($.ui.ddmanager && !this.options.dropBehaviour) {
            dropped = $.ui.ddmanager.drop(this, event);
        }

        //if a drop comes from outside (a sortable)
        if (this.dropped) {
            dropped = this.dropped;
            this.dropped = false;
        }

        if ((this.options.revert === "invalid" && !dropped) || (this.options.revert === "valid" && dropped) || this.options.revert === true || ($.isFunction(this.options.revert) && this.options.revert.call(this.element, dropped))) {
            // Original revert is simply animate to original position. You can add whatever you want before
            $(this.helper).effect('shake').animate(this.originalPosition, parseInt(this.options.revertDuration, 10), function() {
                if (that._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                    that._clear();
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (this._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                this._clear();
            }
        }

        return false;
    },
})

$('#draggable').customDraggable({
    revert: 'invalid',

});

$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '#anything'

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ou82b2k/

Or even better, allow to set the animation you want on revert in the `options`. A bit more complicated, and most likely to interfere with other features, but more flexible. Something like this:

```
$.widget("ui.customDraggable", $.ui.draggable, {
    _mouseStop: function(event) {

        //If we are using droppables, inform the manager about the drop
        var that = this,
            dropped = false;
        if ($.ui.ddmanager && !this.options.dropBehaviour) {
            dropped = $.ui.ddmanager.drop(this, event);
        }

        //if a drop comes from outside (a sortable)
        if (this.dropped) {
            dropped = this.dropped;
            this.dropped = false;
        }

        if ((this.options.revert === "invalid" && !dropped) || (this.options.revert === "valid" && dropped) || this.options.revert === true || ($.isFunction(this.options.revert) && this.options.revert.call(this.element, dropped))) {

           // This allows you to set the animation you want. Since stop event is triggered on animation end, you need the animation to be 'queueable'.
            this.options.revertAnimation.call(this.helper, {originalPosition: this.originalPosition, helper: this.helper});
            $(this.helper).queue( function() {
                if (that._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                    that._clear();
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (this._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                this._clear();
            }
        }

        return false;
    },



});



$('#draggable').customDraggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertAnimation: function(ui){// this option will be called instead of the normal revert
        $(ui.helper).effect('shake').fadeOut().fadeIn().animate(ui.originalPosition, parseInt(500, 10))
    },
    stop: function(){
        console.log('stopped')
    }

});

$('#droppable').droppable({
    accept: '#anything'

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ou82b2k/1/

EDIT: To have the effect only on an invalid target it gets a bit more complicated. There are different ways to do it, one of them would be to set `revert` to `true`, and let the `droppable` accept the `draggable` and manage behaviors on the drop. You have the `dropped` variable that will tell you if the draggable is dropped on a target, if so you decide then whether it should revert or not. Like this for example:

```
...

        if ((this.options.revert === "invalid" && !dropped) || (this.options.revert === "valid" && dropped) || this.options.revert === true || ($.isFunction(this.options.revert) && this.options.revert.call(this.element, dropped))) {
            if (dropped) {
                $(this.helper).effect('shake').animate(this.originalPosition, parseInt(this.options.revertDuration, 10), function () {
                    if (that._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                        that._clear();
                    }
                });
            } else if (!dropped) {
                $(this.helper).animate(this.originalPosition, parseInt(this.options.revertDuration, 10), function () {
                    if (that._trigger("stop", event) !== false) {
                        that._clear();
                    }
                });
            }
          ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juliengregoire/6ou82b2k/2/

Comment: Thank you, great answer :) One additional question. For now the element shakes even when I do not try to drop it on the wrong container (but on anything that is not valid one). How can I distinguish the case when I've dropped element on wrong container and case when I just dropped it on e.g. non-droppable area (`dropped` value is false in both cases)?